# Displaying image in template with Django get_absolute_url

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to display image in template with get_absolute_url model method.

model:

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    ......
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photo/', blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s%s' %(self.last_name, self.photo)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("user_edit", kwargs={"pk": self.id)
```

urls:

```
url(r'^entry/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name='user_edit')
```

template:

```
<img src="{{ userdata.get_absolute_url }}"/>
```

and can successfully get url in template as: [image]

but if I add one more argument in

```
return reverse("user_edit", kwargs={"pk": self.id, 'photo':self.photo})
```

I receive error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /entry/1/edit/
Reverse for 'user_edit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 1,'photo': <ImageFieldFile: photo/_IGP7076.jpg>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['entry/(?P<pk>\\d+)/edit/$']
```

What's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you defined a url named `"user_edit"` which accepts both `pk` and `photo` as named parameters? If your original implementation works with `pk` only then the URL accepts only that much. If you need to pass the `photo` as well then you need to modify the url pattern. Please add the url pattern for `user_edit`.

Comment: Url pattern exists, added above

Comment: It does exist but it only has one named parameter `pk` and not the `photo`. That's why you are getting the error.

Comment: What do you wish to achieve by passing the `photo` in the url?

Comment: I want to display photo on page.Please help to update url.

Comment: We can only help if you can help us understand the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `MEDIA` settings are configured properly, you can retrieve the relative path of the image using the `url` property like so:

```
<img src="{{ userdata.photo.url }}"/>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url

Answer (score 1):

your url pattern does not match:

```
url(r'^entry/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name='user_edit')
```

should be:

```
url(r'^entry/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<photo>[^\/]*)/edit/$',views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name='user_edit')
```

but I would not pass photo url via urlconf. you should rethink your app design for this.

Since you have user object in your context, then you can retrieve his photo url via `user.photo.url` then no need to pass the photo in url.